# How to get showkeys bugfix into tools package distribution

Tags: packages, tools, updating, showkeys

Almost a year ago, the **showkeys** package was updated to v3.16 in response to a bug report:
http://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?pr=tools/4173

Showkeys is supposed to be part of the **tools** distribution.  How do we get the **tools** distribution on CTAN updated to include the update to **showkeys**?
http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tools

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to do it is to check the fix into the latex repository and then it's supposed to appear in the next latex update. Unfortunately there are humans (unpaid volunteer humans as it happens) in the loop at various points and due to a range of issues it didn't happen at the last update. Sorry. Forcing a manual update of a single package also has its own dangers of messing something up and since the package is only for debugging use anyway and the modified file is publicly available from the latex svn repository, leaving it until the next latex updated seemed reasonable. Is it not being on ctan causing you problems?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I actually didn't realize how to see that it's in the SVN repository, which I see now is at http://www.latex-project.org/svnroot/latex2e-public/required/tools.  When do you expect the next LaTeX update to be?